# Prove this random variable has support in the first quadrant only

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $f(t)$ be a density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ with support on the positive half line $(t>0)$. Now show
$$g(x,y) = \frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}$$ has support only in the first quadrant. $(x>0,y>0)$.

This question stumps me because it seems like $g(x,y) \ge 0$ whenever $x+y >0$? So it seems like it would have support to the right of the line $y = -x$?

I suppose one way to argue is that if we are sampling values $X$ and $Y$ according to density $f(\cdot)$, then $\Pr[X < 0] = \Pr[Y < 0] = 0$, thus $X,Y >0$? But I don't think this is a fair assumption.

Furthermore, what would its covariance matrix look like?

I would think it's simply $(\sigma^2 - \mu^2) 1_{2x2}$ since each term in the matrix is either $E[XY]=E[X^2]$ or just $E[X^2]$, and $E[X^2]= Var(X)- E[X]^2 = \sigma^2 - \mu^2$

Comment: I don't think $g$ is a density. Whose covariance matrix are you looking for?

Comment: The question claims that it is

Comment: The covariance matrix of $g$. For example if $f(t)$ is $\phi$, then it's asking for the covariance matrix of the degenerate normal. But in this case we don't know what f is other than its mean and variance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty  g(x,y)dxdy &= 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x+y)}{x+y}dxdy \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(z)}{z}dzdu \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty du \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(z)}{z}dz \\
 &= \infty
\end{align*}
as long as
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(z)}{z}dz > 0 $$

thus $g$ is not a density.